# Bug in polylongdiv?

Tags: packages, debugging, polynom

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polynom}

\begin{document}

\polylongdiv{x^4-1}{x^3+x^2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It leaves out the first `x` in the quotient. How can I fix this?

Comment: It seems really a bug.

Comment: Any suggestions as to how I can add the `x` in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does **NOT** fix the noted bug in `polydiv`.  However, what it does do is allow you to overlay an `x` on the buggy solution, which answers the comment of the OP: "Any suggestions as to how I can add the x in?"  To do this, it uses `\stackinset`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polynom}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}

\stackinset{l}{11.5ex}{t}{0.9ex}{$x$}{\polylongdiv{x^4-1}{x^3+x^2}}

\end{document}
```

[image]